# Event attendee status is not reflected in invite sent to attendees

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am currently experiencing inconsistent behavior when creating a new calendar event via the Graph API.

I am marking an [`attendee`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/attendee) for an [`event`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/event) as `status: Accepted`. When the calendar event is created, I can see this attendee marked as `Accepted` within Outlook. (see below for sample API request)

However, in the invite that goes out to the attendee (and by extension, the attendee's calendar event), the not status is reflected. The event is awaiting a response.

This creates an inconsistency where, from the perspective of the event organizer, the attendee has "Accepted", but from the perspective of the attendee, the event is pending response.

What is the intended behavior here? Can we expect an update in the future that will make this behavior consistent with the above.

Example API request: To create an event, we're posting to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events with a payload like

```
{
   "subject":"Subject",
   "body":{
      "contentType":"Text",
      "content":"Meeting body"
   },
   "start":{
      "dateTime":"2018-04-13T00:00:00Z",
      "timeZone":"UTC"
   },
   "end":{
      "dateTime":"2018-04-13T00:30:00Z",
      "timeZone":"UTC"
   },
   "isAllDay":false,
   "location":{
      "displayName":null
   },
   "attendees":[
      {
         "emailAddress":{
            "address":"redacted@gmail.com",
            "name":"Test Testington"
         },
         "type":"required",
         "status":{
            "response":"accepted"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The response status is stored independently in each mailbox/calendar. Each attendee has their own copy of the `event`. When an update to a meeting is received, the mail server looks up the associated `event` in the recipient's mailbox using the `iCalUId` property. Each `event` in each `mailbox` is a unique record, only linked by this shared `iCalUId`.

Everything the recipient knows about an `event` is provided via the `iCal` object attached to the meeting invite. There isn't a mechanism to "look up" events on a remote server. So while you're marking the attendee as "Accepted", the remove mailbox has no way of knowing this.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for the reply! The main thing I'm trying to figure out is the initial calendar invite. In our parallel Gmail implementation, if we create the event with the attendee "Accepted" than the invite that gmail sends out has the attendee already marked as accepted. However the invite sent out by o365 doesn't reflect this.

Comment: Based on your response, it sounds like maybe the calendar event is being created, the invite goes out, and *then* the attendee is updated to "Accepted" on the original calendar, even though were just making one create request with all of this information

Comment: Technically I believe it simply isn't including the current `PARTSTAT` in the invite but I could be mistaken. Can you add the JSON payload that you're sending to the API to your question?

Comment: Interesting, Just updated my question to include the full payload we're sending to graph 'events' endpoint

Comment: how can we get the updated status of attendee with the graph api